# Navigating in the dynamics 365 CRM App

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-365, dynamics365-app-mobile

I have a  Dynamics CRM 2016 Online installation. I have created a web resource in this application. This web resource is launched from a button in the account list.

On the desktop this works perfectly, it launches a new window and I can do what I need and then navigate to a new record in crm with

```
Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm(entity, entityId);
```

and then close the window with

```
window.close();
```

I can also access this webbresource in the (iOS) phone app. But neither of the above two commands work when the resource has loaded.

I can't navigate from the webresource to a record using any of these commands:

```
Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm(entity, entityId); // throws undefined error
window.open(recordURL); // does nothing
window.location.href = recordURL; // does nothing
```

And I cannot close the webresource with either of these:

```
window.close(); // does nothing
window.history.go(-1); // goes to a blank page (even more infuriating).
```

Are there some specific javascript commands for these things (navigate to record, or go back)? I can't seem to find any references to what commands I should be using in the dynamics 365 app.

Answer (score 0):

[This Microsoft documentation site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481572.aspx#BKMK_SomeFunctionsNotAvailable) has some information about mobile devices:

> "Additionally, Dynamics 365 for **phones does not** support web
>   resources and IFRAMES so the client APIs for these controls won't
>   work. Client APIs for web resources and IFRAMES **are supported** on
>   Dynamics 365 for **tablets** though."
>
> "Dynamics 365 **mobile clients also do not support the window.open
>   method**. If you are looking to open an entity form for a new or
>   existing record, use Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm instead."

So the window functions are not supported. `Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm()` should work though. Maybe a web API request doesn't deliver a required guid for the function call due to a bad internet connection on mobile devices.

Maybe it's just not supported as well, but nowhere documented. Atleast a very similar function `Xrm.Utility.openWebResource()` is not supported as state here: [Xrm.Utility.openWebresource()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602956.aspx#openWebResource)

Keep in mind that you have to use `parent.Xrm` to access the Xrm object inside of webpages that are embedded as an iframe inside a entity form. That counts for webpages opened by `window.open()` too.

In case it will just not work you could still do some kind of conditional behavior or fallback:

```
var isCrmForMobile = (Xrm.Page.context.client.getClient() == "Mobile")
if (isCrmForMobile)
{
   // Code for CRM for phones and tablets only goes here.
}
else
{
   // Code for web browser or CRM for Outlook only goes here.
}
if (Xrm.Page.context.client.getClient() == "Mobile" && Xrm.Page.context.client.getFormFactor() == 3)
{
   // Add code that should only run in CRM for phones here
}
// Code for any client goes here.
```